# JQuery form validation and class change if elements are empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am not a JQuery expert. After trying for 3 days, I have no other option other than asking for help.

I have a dynamic form which gets elements (input, select, radio, textarea) via jquery/ajax.

Now, I want to simply validate the form. If an element is empty, then the form will not be submitted and a Bootstrap class "error" will be added to the empty element. If none of the elements are empty, then the form will be submitted to the desired php page.

This is what I have done so far

```
if (($(this).attr("category")) || ($(this).attr("vcmodel"))) {
    if ($('#category').length) {
        $('#category').addClass('error');
    }
    if ($('#vcmodel').length) {
        $('#vcmodel').addClass('error');
    }
    if ((($(this).attr("category")) && ($('#category').length)) || (($(this).attr("vcmodel")) && ($('#vcmodel').length))) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried ? Perhaps prepare a fiddle ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code. Please check my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just to give you an idea, maybe you can do something like this:

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
    var category = $("#category");
    if(category.val() === "") {
        category.addClass("error");

        // don't submit !
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2eHs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You Can try Jquery validation plugin. otherwise you will try this type of method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var valid;
        valid = true;
        $('.yourInputClass').each(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value == ''){
                valid = false;
                $(this).addClass('error');              
            }
        });
        if(valid){
            $this.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it is not working. Also, the form is being sent to the action page when I click on the submit button!

Comment: you can try on method like this. $("body" ).on( "click", "form input.submit", function(e) {

Comment: Still not working! The form is still being submitted while all fields are empty.

Comment: First check your javascript code working properly. copy paste this code.  $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('ok')
});